# Python pandas to select a row value after group by

Tags: python, group-by, count

May I know how to select a row of values which has max count number after grouping by a column

Examples:

```
STATE COUNTY POPULATION
1     5571   1000
2     3421   2000
3     6781   3000
2     1234   4000
2     3344   6600   
1     5566   9900
```

I want to find the STATE with max number of count of county, select STATE and COUNTY to show only, without POPULATION.

Answer should be, but i dont know how to code it in python. Thanks for help

```
STATE   COUNTY
2       3
```

Comment: Hint: `df.groupby('STATE')['COUNTRY'].nunique()`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
u = df.groupby('STATE')['COUNTRY'].size()
v = u[u.index==u.idxmax()].reset_index()
```

---

**v:**

`STATE  COUNTRY                                                                                                       0      2        3`

Approach:

1. Group by STATE and then use `nunique` if you want to count distinct values or `size` on COUNTRY Column.
2. get the index of the row where count is the max.